# Better to learn the same small set for multiple epochs then go to the next or learn from each one time repeatedly for multiple times?

Tags: neural-networks, image-recognition, python

I don't know if I worded the title correctly.

I have a big dataset (300000 of images after augumentation) and I've splitted it into 10 parts, because I can't convert the images into a numpy and save it, the file would be too large.

Now, I have a neural network (Using keras with tf). My question is, is it better to train each file individually for X epochs (File 1 for 5 epochs, then File 2 for 5 epochs, etc.), or should I do an epoch for each, repeatedly (File 1 for an epoch, File 2 for an epoch, etc., and repeat for 5 times).

I've used the first and I get an accuracy of about 88%. Whould I get an improvement by doing the latter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small set for multiple epochs causes overfit, so expose entire data in one epoch, then augment (change a littel bit), and train again. Use small amount of dropout also.

```
I have a big dataset (300000 of images after augumentation) and I've splitted it into 10 parts, because I can't convert the images into a numpy and save it, the file would be too large.
```

Do not store augmented data, just do augment with function right after next epoch and overwrite the dataset array